# Python regex how to remove string at the end of sentence that starts with - and ends with a comma?

Tags: python, regex

I have strings like

```
docs = ["This is blue -Gary,.", "Let's go swim. Sounds good -Mark,",
         "How are you? Mark says yes. Let's go - Grant,"]
```

I want to remove the name if it in the last sentence and in between the '-' and ',' but I can't figure out how to do it.

Desired output

```
docs = ["This is blue", "Let's go swim. Sounds good",
             "How are you? Mark says yes. Let's go"]
```

I have tried

```
re.sub(r'_^\b.*?[,]\s+', '', x))
```

But this isn't doing anything.

Comment: Try `[re.sub(r'\s*-\s*[^\W\d_]+,$', '', x) for x in docs]`

Comment: Thanks, this works for the what I originally put. What if there is a period at the end of the sentence? I added it into the example since I forgot it before and realized what you put isn't working for sentences like that.

Comment: I removed the '$' and then it worked . Thanks

Comment: If it worked, why not accept/upvote the answer that worked for you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

```
\s*-\s*[^\W\d_]+,(?=\.?$)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/h9Q8q1/1). *Details*:

- `\s*-\s*` - a hyphen enclosed with zero or more whitespaces
- `[^\W\d_]+` - one or more letters
- `,` - a comma
- `(?=\.?$)` - a positive lookahead that requires an optional dot and end of string position immediately to the right of the current position.

See the Python demo:

```py
import re
rx = re.compile( r'\s*-\s*[^\W\d_]+,(?=\.?$)' )
docs = ["This is blue -Gary,.", "Let's go swim. Sounds good -Mark,",
         "How are you? Mark says yes. Let's go - Grant,"]
print( [rx.sub('', x) for x in docs] )
```

Output:

```
['This is blue.', "Let's go swim. Sounds good", "How are you? Mark says yes. Let's go"]
```